# How can I revert back to a previous cell code on Google Colab if pressing control + z pastes the code and I can't undo it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, google-colaboratory

What is the solution to revert back to a previous cell code in Google Colab if pressing control + z pastes the code and I can't undo it?

Currently, pressing control + z in Google Colab pastes the cell code.
For example, when I wrote:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd # I accidentally deleted this
```

And then I pressed control + z, the code became:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import pandas as 
import pandas as
```

However, when I search, it usually returns to its normal state.

Comment: Control+z usually is Undo, not Paste.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a display problem, not a content problem.